# Reading pdf or word file with php

Tags: php

how can i open and read file PDF or Word file with php ??

```
 <?php

echo "hello";
$myfile = fopen("SoftwareTesting&Engineering_day1.pdf", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("SoftwareTesting&Engineering_day1.pdf"));
fclose($myfile);

?>
```

Comment: and do you need also to be able to edit while opening?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it with php fopen(). You may be able to display some junk data only. Because word documents and pdf files are not simple text files rather complicated than plain text. If you have a simple text file then you can go along with php file handling functions. If you really want to manipulate word documents and pdf documents then you have to use a good library for that.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord
http://phpword.codeplex.com/
https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser

are some of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `header` to the content type of the file (see PHP.net for information). Note: You should not print out any contents before setting the header. Also note that the client needs correct plugins to display the file. Otherwise it will be offered to download or you see the binary content of the file.

Then you could `echo file_get_content(path)` to print out the file content itself.

(untested).